# Install Logcheck / Logtail in Rocky Linux 8

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, centos8, rocky-linux

I need to install logtail / logcheck in Rocky Linux 8. We have an application that uses it and we are migrating that from Centos 7 to Rocky 8.

Yum doesn't find it.

```
[root@myserver ~]# yum provides logtail
Last metadata expiration check: 0:37:59 ago on Mon 15 Nov 2021 12:43:04 PM CET.
Error: No Matches found

[root@myserver ~]# yum repolist
repo id                                          repo name
appstream                                        Rocky Linux 8 - AppStream
baseos                                           Rocky Linux 8 - BaseOS
epel                                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-modular                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
extras                                           Rocky Linux 8 - Extras
powertools                                       Rocky Linux 8 - PowerTools
virtualmin                                       RHEL/CentOS 8 - x86_64 - Virtualmin
virtualmin-universal                             Virtualmin Distribution Neutral Packages
```

I can see EPEL is already added. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded from source and compiled it to run on Rocky Linux 8.